# some issue about sipp

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk, freeswitch

I wrote a program to run sipp.  But It cannot auto exit after It call a large total numbers, or It has some other ways to know the sipp has completed,

And second issues: When it call after count number, The call become very slow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: do small amount of call(100) and start it again with next portion.